# Python 3.3.2 - Sorting a List of Names based on a Number

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

I need to sort a list of names based on the number they are coupled with. An example of the data I have is:

```
[['Bob Person', 10], ['Josh Winner', 15], ['Jimmy Dexter', 5], ['Mary Goodsprings', 15]]
```

A normal sort would do this:

```
[['Bob Person', 10], ['Jimmy Dexter', 5], ['Josh Winner', 15], ['Mary Goodsprings', 15]]
```

The sort I want to conduct should be based on the largest number they are coupled with. But, if the numbers are equal, then it should resort to names. Like this:

```
[['Josh Winner', 15], ['Mary Goodsprings', 15], ['Bob Person', 10], ['Jimmy Dexter', 5]]
```

Notice how Mary and Josh are both tied, but Josh is still out front because J comes before M.

I have pretty much no clue on how to do this, apart from the fact that I should use the `key` function of `sort()`.

Comment: You have an error in "normal sort" example, first and second items should be replaced

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `-item[1]` to sort in a descending order, with `item[0]` for the numbers tie.

```
>>> data = [['Bob Person', 10], ['Josh Winner', 15], ['Jimmy Dexter', 5], ['Mary Goodsprings', 15]]
>>> sorted(data, key=lambda item: (-item[1], item[0]))
[['Josh Winner', 15], ['Mary Goodsprings', 15], ['Bob Person', 10], ['Jimmy Dexter', 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the Python sort is [guaranteed to be stable](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Sort_Stability_and_Complex_Sorts) (meaning that the order is preserved when multiple items have the same key), you can sort the list in multiple runs.  The most important criterion comes last.

```
import operator

data = [['Bob Person', 10], ['Josh Winner', 15], ['Jimmy Dexter', 5], ['Mary Goodsprings', 15]]
data.sort()
data.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```